# Perspective projection matrix with a non-orthogonal near plane

Tags: opengl, directx, projection, clipping, projection-matrix

I'm trying to figure out a way to provide such a perspective projection matrix to a shader that the "near" plane wouldn't necessarily be orthogonal to the camera vector. More specifically, I'm basically trying to clip all vertices above a certain y-coordinate, but I don't have access to the shader programs themselves. Is there such a matrix that would throw those vertices with a y-coordinate over some specific value outside of the clip space?

Comment: Hi there!  [Modifying the Projection Matrix to Perform Oblique Near-Plane Clipping](http://www.terathon.com/code/oblique.html) seems to be what you want - let me know if this describes your use case and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Sweet! This is exactly what I was looking for, by the looks of it :)

Comment: If that solves your problem, please consider writing up your solution as an Answer. It's totally OK to answer your own questions on this site. :)